# About endmarks in thmtools

Tags: math-mode, theorems, thmtools

If I use the `thmtools´ package I get poorly placed endmarks (it appears on the next line) when ending a proof with a centered mathematical equation. How can I fix this?

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, twoside]{amsart}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}


\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amsfonts, mathrsfs, amsfonts}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\declaretheorem{theorem}
\declaretheoremstyle[name=Proof, numbered=no, qed=\qedsymbol]{myproof}
\declaretheorem[style=myproof]{proof}
%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%
\begin{proof} For all $a,b\in\mathbf{R}$ we have
  \[ (a+b)^2=a^2 2ab +b^2. \]
\end{proof}


%%%%%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your code doesn't compile; instead, it crashes with `LaTeX Error: Command \proof already defined.`. Please consider editing the code so that it at least compiles.

Comment: if you use the `proof` environment already provided by `amsart` (which incorporates `amsthm` and loads `amsmath` and `amsfonts`, so you don't have to specify them separately), you can use `\qedhere` before the `\]` that ends the proof to adjust the positioning.

Comment: This is not `thmtools`, this is a well-known problem with `amsthm` and end-marks. Use `\qedhere`, as barbara beeton suggested.

Answer (score 2):

if you use the `proof` environment already provided by `amsart` (which incorporates `amsthm`
and loads `amsmath` and `amsfonts`, so you don't have to specify them separately),
you can use `\qedhere` before the `\]` that ends the proof to adjust the positioning.